# Caching rest requests in angular services

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 6, 
I have a service called 'UserService' which has a method named 'getUserInfo()' that gets some of the user's data from the server and saves them.
There are several components that call this method, but I want my service to make an HTTP request just for the first time that it doesn't have the user's information, and for other 'getUserInfo()' calls, it should provide the data that already has been fetched from the server. 
What's the best practice to implement this?

Comment: Next time post what you've done so far. How can we help you? Anyway, Angular use the Guard to do that. When the component do the http call you can also check if there is the user's information stored in an object you've saved. If there are, the function that does the request will emit an empty observable. If there aren't, the service does the call and you store the information in this object. There are some way to do this. Use a common var or a BehaviorSubject for example. If you need an example code let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply save the information in a property of your service and provide it if it's available. Take a look at the code bellow.

```
import { Restangular } from 'ngx-restangular';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

export interface UserInfo {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' // for angular 6
})
export class UserService
  userInfo: UserInfo;
  constructor(private: rest: Restangular) {}
  getUserInfo(): Observable<UserInfo> {
    if (this.userInfo) {
      return of(this.userInfo);
    }
    return this.rest
      .one('/userInfo/')
      .get()
      .pipe(
        map<UserInfo, UserInfo>(data => {
          this.userInfo = data;
          return data;
        })
      );
  }
}
```

Please Note:

1. `of` was a method of `Observable` in rxjs 5 which is now a function (in rxjs 6).
2. `rest` is from [ngx-restangular](https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular)
3. The reason the I've returned `of(this.userInfo)` instead of `this.userInfo` is that, you're going to subscribe to this method so this method has to return an Observable.
4. `of` is equivalent to the code bellow:

---

```
return new Observable(observer => {
  observer.next(this.userInfo);
  observer.complete();
  return { unsubscribe() {} };
});
```